# Regular expression for a time format

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to search for cells in a column containing a time in the format of 00:00 using the `MATCH` function. I have tried things similar to `MATCH("??:??",A:A)` and `MATCH("?*:?*",A:A)` with no luck. How can I form a regular expression of 2 digits, then a colon, then 2 digits?

Comment: Have you ever used regex? What regex expressions have you tried?

Comment: Is the time that is stored in your cells formatted as time or text? If it's formatted as time, then the actual value is a decimal that you are searching for. Also, the `match()` function in excel doesn't take regex as an argument, so regex isn't really the way to go here.

Comment: It is stored as the custom format of hh:mm. Is there no way to use `match()` and use the hh:mm format as the first argument, similar to how "ZZZ" as the first argument returns true if any word is found?

Comment: @pnuts - Boooo, you beat me literally by .5 seconds :P

Comment: The `MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)` from your last question was not the part that found if any had text.  It found the last cell in which there was text.

Comment: Ok, but how can I find the last cell in which there is a time in the format of hh:mm, rather than text?

Comment: @pnuts that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times what is displayed to us in excel isn't the actual value. Time and Dates are one such time. Generally if you enter a time into excel `3:55` it will convert that automatically to excel's time format, which is a decimal number: `0.163194444444444`, but it formats it automatically to "mm:ss" just like you entered it.

So... when you try to `=MATCH()` using a wildcard, you aren't going to find a hit since the value in the cell is actually that decimal number.

Instead you have to convert the value of the cells you are searching into a text format. You can do that with the `=TEXT()` formula. Assuming your data starts in A1 you can put in `B1`:

```
=Text(A1, "mm:ss")
```

Now the returned value from that formula still looks like the `mm:ss` format, but it's now text. The underlying value is actually `3:55`. No funny business. You can now base your wild card search of `"*:*"` off of this column:

```
=Match("*:*", B1:B10, 0)
```

If you want to do this all in one formula you can use an Array formula (or CSE):

```
=Match("*:*", Text(A1:A10,"mm:ss"),0)
```

Using Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of Enter) when you enter the formula.